# How to show only 1 row given 1 column has the same value in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a sample output of this right now: Let's call it table X and attributes x.name, x.title, x.best x.lowest

```
NAME                 TITLE                     BEST            LOWEST 
-------------------- ------------------------- --------------- -------
Andy Aardverk        Avarice is Good           CARP             215.95
Andy Aardverk        Avarice is Good           YRB Bronze       215.95
Andy Aardverk        Yon-juu Hachi             CARP              41.95
Andy Aardverk        Yon-juu Hachi             YRB Bronze        43.95
```

Given the fact that the last column has a duplicate value of 215.95, I would like to show only 1 row out of the 2 rows containing the same value.  So I would like it to show something like this

```
NAME                 TITLE                     BEST            LOWEST 
-------------------- ------------------------- --------------- -------
Andy Aardverk        Avarice is Good           CARP             215.95
Andy Aardverk        Yon-juu Hachi             CARP              41.95
Andy Aardverk        Yon-juu Hachi             YRB Bronze        43.95
```

I know I can just take out X.best and it will give me the unique row in regards to X.lowest, but I need the attribute X.best for another query later on. 
I've tried

```
select distinct x.name, x.title, x.best, x.lowest
```

but it doesn't help.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Any logic why you are returning CARP vs. YRB Bronze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting to display a single row if the lowest column is duplicated, or if the name, title and lowest columns are duplicated?

Usually you'd have criteria for which row to keep, but if it doesn't matter, a simple `GROUP BY` with `MAX` or `MIN` should work.  This assumes you care about the name and title being distinct as well:

```
SELECT name, title, MIN(best) best, lowest
FROM tablex
GROUP BY name, title, lowest
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56a40/2)

If you only care about distinct lowest fields, you can utilize `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT name, title, best, lowest
FROM (
     SELECT name, title, best, lowest, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lowest ORDER BY lowest) rn
     FROM tablex
  ) X
WHERE rn = 1
```

[More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56a40/5)

Comment: Yeah, I only wanted to display a single row if lowest column was duplicated and the 2nd part you provided fixed it! Thanks

Comment: If I wanted to make a query that does that above AND selects the minimum lowest if there's a repeat title (rows 3 and 4), would I just use the min aggregate function to display only rows 1 and 3?

Comment: never mind, I used the same thing you showed me and it worked :)